# n-sphere: inside is bigger than outside in terms of radius

Tags: linear-algebra, spheres

Recently I started playing with n-spheres for my classification problem and end up with some weird results.

Let's say that we have m points $p_i$, each is n-dimensional. I want to find the minimum covering n-sphere, centered at $C_c$ and has radius $r_c$. And it can be found easily by solving following equation:

$${p_i},{C_c} \in {R^n},i = 1 \ldots m$$

$$\mathop {\min }\limits_{{r_c} \ge {{\left\| {{p_{_i}} - {C_c}} \right\|}_2}} {}_{\left( {{r_c},{C_c}} \right)}\left\{ {{r_c}} \right\}
$$

This is an outer n-sphere which covers all $p_i$. The solution is unique and exists.

Now I also want to find a maximum n-sphere which doesn't have any $p_i$ in it but centered at $C_f$ which is inside the covering sphere. I call this as a maximum fitting n-sphere, and I can solve it using following equation:

$$\mathop {\max }\limits_{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{r_f} \le {{\left\| {{p_{_i}} - {C_f}} \right\|}_2}}\\{{r_c} \ge {{\left\| {{C_c} - {C_f}} \right\|}_2}}\end{array}} {}_{\left( {{r_f},{C_f}} \right)}\left\{ {{r_f}} \right\}
$$

This one is not as easy as above to solve since it is not positive semi definite but I can find some solutions.

In summary, I want to find n-spheres shown like below image:

**Blue**: Minimum Covering n-sphere

**Orange**: Maximum Fitting n-sphere

[image: Minimum Covering and Maximum Fitting Spheres]

Now the problem, if all my equations are correct, I always end up with something $r_f$ > $r_c$. To me this is not logical. Could you please briefly verify my equations and tell me why always end up with n-spheres which have bigger radius inside than outside?

Comment: In the second optimization problem, are $r_c$ and $C_c$ fixed to be the optimizers of the first optimization problem? And when you say you "end up with something..." how are you getting the solution, given that you have been editing the definition of the optimization problems in this problem statement in the last few minutes?

Comment: First question's answer is yes. About second note, I fixed couple of typo problems in the equations since this is my first attempt to post with equations, sorry :)

Comment: My second question still stands: when you say "you end up with $r_f > r_c$", are you solving analytically or using software? And in either case, are you solving the current formulation of the optimization problem?

Comment: First optimization problem can be solved analytically but I don't think second one can be. I used Gurobi (https://gurobi.com) to solve both optimization problems.

Comment: The maximum fitting n-sphere is centered inside the minimum fitting n-sphere. However, given your conditions, that doesn't mean it needs to be inside the minimum n-sphere. It's radius can be up to twice as big as $r_c$ . Here is the simplest example illustrating the problem (3 points with n = 2 ): 

https://i.imgur.com/z9Wmv2u.png

Comment: @user3257842 thank you for this perfect illustration, you are right about my second definition doesn't fully describe the problem, I understood my mistake now. Do you have any idea also what it would be a nicer definition?

Comment: A "natural" definition for the "maximum fitting n-sphere" could be "the largest sphere which fits inside the convex cover (convex hull)  of our points".  This has a unique solution and can be solved analytically (just like the minimum fitting n-sphere). 

https://i.imgur.com/wRk4T2V.png

Comment: @user3257842 since you illustrate my mistake, if you make your comment an answer, I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum fitting $n$-sphere is centered inside the minimum fitting $n$-sphere. However, that doesn't mean it needs to be inside the minimum n-sphere. It's radius can be up to twice as big as $r_c$ . The simplest example illustrating the problem occurs with $n=2$ and $3$ points:

[image]

A more natural definition for the "maximum fitting n-sphere" could be "the largest sphere which fits inside the convex cover (convex hull) of our points". This has a unique solution and can be solved analytically, just like the minimum fitting $n$-sphere.

[image]

Comment: I updated inner n-sphere equation like that: $$\mathop {\max }\limits_{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{r_f} \le {{\left\| {{p_{_i}} - {C_f}} \right\|}_2}}\\{{r_c} \ge {{\left\| {{C_c} - {C_f}} \right\|}_2} + {r_f}}\end{array}} {}_{\left( {{r_f},{C_f}} \right)}\left\{ {{r_f}} \right\}$$ Thanks.